# Excluding records that match keywords on a specific date

Tags: crystal-reports

I've been tasked with pulling some data from a large database and I'm having trouble excluding specific records.

I have a table that has pay records for about 3,500 people. Pay is broken down into individual paycodes, a single user will usually have anywhere from 1-50ish entries per day. Right now, I have a report that will return all entries that match 6 specific pay codes, grouped by week and by user. I am then adding up the pay times (all stored in seconds) and then dividing by the number of employees who had one of those pay codes that week to get the average paytime of those codes only of all employees who worked that week.

This part works pretty well. I have some formula fields and running totals that do the heavy lifting, and for example, for the week of Jan 6 2019 I have 2614 active employees, and of the pay codes I am interested in, they worked an average of 36:51/w.

The selection criteria is simple:
{PayInterface.OpDate} in {?Date Range} and
{PayInterface.PSCode}=["REG","RGA","OTW","SBY","REA","TRN"]

However, I want to exclude any employee who had another specific pay code that week. I had hoped I could put exclusion criteria in the weekly group selection criteria like this:

{PayInterface.PSCode}<>["STD","UIN","LOA"]

...but it's not removing anyone, presumably because it wasn't bringing back those records in the first place.
I want *no* records for that week for that person if any of those codes match.

I can't seem to figure out how to tell it if someone matches LOA, then get rid of them completely, I don't want their values to be included in my calculations. I don't want to just suppress them, because they'll still be included in my running totals and formulas.

Comment: Hi Jon, You could try writing an sql expression. I would start with a Case statement when you say PayInterface.PSCode IN () and PayInterface.PSCode NOT IN () Then 1 else 0. Then add this in the record = 1